# Why getLastKnownLocation(provider) doesn't return null after clearTestProviderLocation(provider)

Tags: android, mocking, location

I was assuming that getLastKnownLocation does return null for a given provider after calling clearTestProviderLocation for same provider.

Why ? because documentation says for clearTestProviderLocation;

> Removes any mock location associated with the given provider.

```
public void test() throws SecurityException {
    String provider = "TEST";
    Location location = new Location(provider);
    location.setAccuracy(100);
    location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    }

    mLocationManager.addTestProvider(provider, false, false, 
        false, false, false ,false, false, 0, 0);

    mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(provider, true);
    mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(provider, location);

    Location locationBefore = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    Log.d(TAG, locationBefore.toString());

    mLocationManager.clearTestProviderLocation(provider);

    Location locationAfter = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    Log.d(TAG, locationAfter.toString());
}
```

After running test method, locationBefore and locationAfter are same!

And logs like below,

```
Location[TEST 0.000000,0.000000 acc=100 et=+4d10h54m26s455ms mock]
Location[TEST 0.000000,0.000000 acc=100 et=+4d10h54m26s455ms mock]
```

What i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

As [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) for `getLastKnownLocation` says

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

you need to first disable the test provider for `getLastKnownLocation` to return null.

Comment: But you are missing something; i did set location for `TEST` provider only one time (No more attempts),  so after calling `clearTestProviderLocation("TEST")`, there must be zero location for TEST  provider. And as a result, `getLastKnownLocation("TEST")` must return null